# How to fix confirm delete not working in codeigniter, ajax?

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, sql-delete

what am I missing?
after "ok" in "are you sure you want to delete", I get nothing. But when i try to alert $id it works. Is it ajax problem?

I have this in my footer.php

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.confirm-delete').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            confirmDialog = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
            if(confirmDialog)
            {
                var id = $(this).val();
                // alert(id);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url: "/employee/confirmdelete/"+id,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Data deleted successfuly");
                       
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });

</script>
```

I have this in my routes.php

```
$route['employee/confirmdelete/(:any)']['DELETE'] = 'Frontend/EmployeeController/delete/$1';
```

My delete button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger confirm-delete" value="<?= $row->id; ?> ">Confirm Delete</button>
```

My delete function in controller

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $this->load->model('EmployeeModel');
    $this->EmployeeModel->deleteEmployee($id);  
    redirect(base_url('employee'));
}
```

my model delete function

```
public function deleteEmployee($id)
{
    return $this->db->delete('employee', ['id' => $id]);
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url: "/employee/confirmdelete/"+id,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Data deleted successfuly");
                       
                    }
                });
```

to this

```
$.ajax({                    
                    url: "/employee/confirmdelete/"+id,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "JSON"
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Data deleted successfuly");
                       
                    }
                });
```

Comment: already solved it, thanks :)